# technique for avoiding seeing a 'scroll effect' when changing background image position

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, sprite, css-sprites

I am using a sprite as a background image for showing different button states.  When I change the position I am seeing it scroll and therefore seeing it go through several 'states' before reaching the appropriate position.

Any suggestions on how to avoid this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let's see your code. We can't help with an issue without knowing what you're doing.

Comment: I'd go with @MichaelIrigoyen and say, show us your code.. Bottom line is theres a number of ways to do any given thing.. what you are currently doing however ties into how to fix the issue your having specifically, otherwise all you will get is a bunch of answers that may not help anything remotely close to your exact needs.

Comment: yeah, this was fairly standard stuff.  There was a transition on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a transition up the inheritance tree.

transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out 0s